# CustomView lifecycle onDetachedFromWindow() not fired

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm animating custom View with ValueAnimator and used below code to stop animator when view detaches from the screen. But I realized that when Application is removed from window manager by either Recents (Overview) or Home button `onDetachedFromWindow()` is not called:

> The way I was canceling ValueAnimator:

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        mSqueezebarAnimator?.start()
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        mSqueezebarAnimator?.cancel()
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }
```

> What I do now:

```
override fun onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility: Int) {
        super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility)

        mSqueezebarAnimator?.let {
            if (it.isStarted && visibility in setOf(View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE)){
                it.cancel()
            }else if (it.isStarted.not()) {
                it.start()
            }
        }
    }
```

I just removed `onAttachedToWindow/onDetachedFromWindow` and added `onWindowVisibilityChanged` instead. What I would like to know is drawbacks of this solution, I mean what could potentially go wrong?

Please, note that I don't want to control the view from Activity lifecycle methods

Answer (score 0):

If you look the source code of a component whose scenario resembles yours, for instance ProgressBar, you see that in both of the callbacks `onVisibilityAggregated` and `onDetachedFromWindow` the animation is stopped. In my opinion, it doesn't pose a problem for your case as well.

Comment: If this (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java) is what you mean, they don't call `onWindowVisibilityChanged()`. If not link to source code would be much appreciated for verification